# Three fixed width columns for cv entry

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, sectioning, cv

I'm in the process of writting my cv in LaTeX. I need to display the information in such a way that for each entry I have 3 left aligned items. The first being the date period, the second the description and the third the location. Each one of the three columns must have a different fixed width. (By this I mean that I need to be able to set the dimensions of each column myself.)

### For example:

```
WORK SECTION TITLE

2008-2010         SOME PLACE I WORKED                            City, Country 
                  Desctiption of the job. Could be more than
                  one line for example.

2004-2008         ANOTHER PLACE I WORKED IN                      City, Country


EDUCATION SECTION TITLE

2002-2007         NAME OF THE UNIVERSITY                         City, Country
                  Name of the department                                      
                  Specialty

PERSONAL SKILLS

Languages         English
                  French
                  Note that the last column is empty in this
                  case.
```

The hard part is that this structure must be preserved through the whole document. By this I mean that for different sections (for example, the work and the education sections) the column width must match and the section titles must be aligned with the date entry.

I've thought about the `tabular` environment, but I can't think of how to fix the column width and most importantly how to align the left items on the `tabular` environment with the section titles that are outside of the tabular environment.

I don't know if saying this is useful but I'm compiling with XeTeX and I'm using a custom class based on the article class. For the section titles I'm using the `titlesec` package:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\scshape\raggedright}
  {}{0em}
  {}
  [\titlerule]
```

This way I get a horizontal line below each section title.

Comment: Are you aware of `moderncv` class for resumes? BTW you can use `tabularx` for the above.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of moderncv and the other cv classes. I don't want to use them since I want to make my cv exactly the way I want.

I solved the problem using the tabular environment after I figured out how to fix the column width. It is a very bad solution though since after font change or size for example I have to edit the width manually. But for now it works. So if someone can give me a better solution it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: with `tabularx` or `tabu` or `longtabu` you have self-adjusting column widths (`X` columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be more resistent to font changes (Try to set the '12pt' option and uncomment `\usepackage{palatino}`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\frstCVcell}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}
\section*{WORK SECTION TITLE}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\frstCVcell}Xc}
2008-2010 & SOME PLACE I WORKED & City, Country\\
& Desctiption of the job. Could be more than one line for example. & \\
2004-2008 & ANOTHER PLACE I WORKED IN & City, Country
\end{tabularx}

\section*{EDUCATION SECTION TITLE}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\frstCVcell}Xc}
2002-2007 & NAME OF THE UNIVERSITY & City, Country\\
& Name of the department & \\
& Specialty &
\end{tabularx}

\section*{PERSONAL SKILLS}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\frstCVcell}Xc}
Languages & English & \\
& French &
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

(You can play around with the `\frstCVcell` macro to customize the solution to your needs. It simply contains the width of the first cell.)

### Output

[image]