# How can I change the position of inputs in cventry?

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to do a CV in LaTeX but I don't like the output I get with `\moderncvstyle{banking}`  and I'd like to customise it a bit. I would like to get a banking style but with dates on the left side. Is it possible? Can I customize a `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}`? I've been looking for something similar and I found this question: [Three fixed width columns for cv entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145871/three-fixed-width-columns-for-cv-entry). Can I get something like this but using a `tabularx` environment, to typeset the arguments of `\cventry` according to the layout I want?

I would like to get something like this:

[image]

For that reason, I asked If is possible to organize the arguments in `\cventry`. I mean, I would like to get a Banking style with date similar to a classic style using `\moderncvstyle{classic}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}


\moderncvstyle{banking}                                   

\moderncvcolor{black}
\nopagenumbers{}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Name}{Surname}

\phone[mobile]{+00~(000)~000~000}         

\email{whatever@gmail.com}                               

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle



\section{Education}
\cventry\hfill{Sept. 2006--Sept.2013}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}


\end{document}
```

I wuold like to do something similar to this solution [classic title and banking body style mixed (moderncv)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146770/classic-title-and-banking-body-style-mixed-moderncv)

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following lines in your preamble so we redefine `\cventry` to look the way you've described in your picture:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} && {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #2} & {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}}& \\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}


\moderncvstyle{banking}

\moderncvcolor{black}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Name}{Surname}

\phone[mobile]{+00~(000)~000~000}

\email{whatever@gmail.com}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} && {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #2} & {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}}& \\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle



\section{Education}
\cventry{Sept.2006--Sept.2013}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here I write one solution to do something similar what I wanted it in some sections.

```
\section{Cmputer skills}

\begin{center}

% Set widths about columns
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} @{\hspace{0.9cm}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{16cm}}

\textbf{Whatever} & A, B, C, D... \\

\textbf{Whatever2} & AA, BB, CC, DD...\\

\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```