# Three column line with fixed width for first column on baseline grid

Tags: tables, context, columns, grid-typesetting

I'm trying to format work headings in a resume that meet the following constraints:

- The `company name` is left aligned and takes up a fixed width, e.g. 2.5cm.
- The `job titles` are all left aligned with each other.
- The years are right aligned at `\textwidth`.
- The text sits on a baseline grid.

Like so:

```
Work Experience

Bar Company        Job Title                 2017-present
Job description....

Foo Company        Job Title                    2015-2017
Job description....
```

This is possible with a table as described in [Three fixed width columns for cv entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145871/three-fixed-width-columns-for-cv-entry).  The problem with a table is that it's more difficult to align to a baseline grid than using a one line paragraph.

Here's kind of what I want to write:

```
\hbox to 4cm {Bar Company} Job Title \hfill 2017-present
```

Full context and MWE:

I'm using Context with a baseline grid with two columns.  `\WorkHeading` and `\WorkHeadingTable` are the relevant commands.

```
\setuppapersize[letter]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\define\GoldenRatio{0.61996}
\defineparagraphs[GoldenColumns][n=2]
\setupparagraphs[GoldenColumns][1][width=\GoldenRatio\textwidth]
\define[3]\WorkHeading{#1 -- #2 \hfill #3}

\starttexdefinition WorkHeadingTable #1#2#3
  \startembeddedxtable[option=stretch,loffset=-1.8pt,roffset=-2.1pt]
    \startxrow
      \startxcell[width=4cm] #1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell #2 \stopxcell
      \startxcell \hfill #3 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopembeddedxtable
\stoptexdefinition

\showgrid
\showframe

\starttext
\startGoldenColumns
Elon Musk
\blank[3*line]

Work Experience

\WorkHeading{Tesla}{CEO}{2016-present}
\startitemize
\item Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique
  imperdiet.  Vestibulum convallis, lorem a tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit,
  vitae placerat urna tortor vitae lacus.
\item Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque.
\stopitemize

\WorkHeadingTable{Solar City}{CEO}{2012-present}
\startitemize
\item Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit.
\item Donec at pede.
\stopitemize

\GoldenColumns
elon-musk@tesla.com
\blank[3*line]
Rockets

Praesent augue. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.  Donec at pede.Praesent fermentum
tempor tellus.
\stopGoldenColumns
\stoptext
```

[image: Minimal Working Example (Context Mkiv)]

Comment: Why do you insist on using a table when `\hbox to 4cm {...}` works just fine?

Comment: `\hbox to 4cm{Foo} Bar \hfill 2016-present` places Foo on it's own line.  I want all text on the same line.

Comment: `\dontleavehmode\hbox to 4cm{Foo} Bar \hfill 2016-present`

Comment: Thanks! Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A table is unnecessary at this point and also feels kind of overkill.  You already proposed a solution yourself, namely

```
\hbox to 4cm {Bar Company} Job Title \hfill 2017-present
```

Then you noticed, that this gets split across lines.  The reason for that is that in TeX a box does not start a new paragraph.  The hbox will be appended to the existing vertical list and only the letter `J` of »Job Title« will start the paragraph.  Therefore you manually have to start the paragraph before the box.  You can do this by saying either `\dontleavehmode` or, if you want to suppress the indentation box (in case you have non-zero `\parindent`), with `\noindent`.

Furthermore I presume that you'd like to have the contents of the hbox left-aligned.  This can easily be achieved by inserting filling glue to the right of the content, i.e. `\hbox to 4cm{Bar Company\hfil}`.  Otherwise the interword space would be stretched such that the content fills the whole box, which is probably not desired in this case.  (Also you would get a message in the log about an underfull hbox).

```
\setuppapersize[letter]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\define\GoldenRatio{0.61996}
\defineparagraphs[GoldenColumns][n=2]
\setupparagraphs[GoldenColumns][1][width=\GoldenRatio\textwidth]
\define[3]\WorkHeading{%
  \dontleavehmode
  \hbox to 4cm{#1\hfil} #2 \hfill #3}

\showgrid
\showframe

\starttext
\startGoldenColumns
Elon Musk
\blank[3*line]

Work Experience

\WorkHeading{Tesla}{CEO}{2016-present}
\startitemize
\item Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique
  imperdiet.  Vestibulum convallis, lorem a tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit,
  vitae placerat urna tortor vitae lacus.
\item Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque.
\stopitemize

\WorkHeading{Solar City}{CEO}{2012-present}
\startitemize
\item Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna. Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit.
\item Donec at pede.
\stopitemize

\GoldenColumns
elon-musk@tesla.com
\blank[3*line]
Rockets

Praesent augue. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.  Donec at pede.Praesent fermentum
tempor tellus.
\stopGoldenColumns
\stoptext
```

[image]